# Listbox outofbound error

Tags: java, gwt, listbox, gwt2, uibinder

I have a trying to put value from arrayList to List box. but it gives me error out of bound exception.

`getListValue()` returns arrayList.

```
for(int i = 0;i<getListValue().size();i++){
                System.out.println("qsdq " +getListValue().toString()+" "+ getListValue().size());
                listBox.addItem(getListValue().get(i)); // ErrorPoint
            }
```

**output**
qsdq [xyz,  abc] 2

Stacktrace

```
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: null
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ListBox.checkIndex(ListBox.java:595)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ListBox.setValue(ListBox.java:511)
    at com.client.GUI.MultivaluedPopup.getListBox(MultivaluedPopup.java:92) // error point
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably add the items first. The `setValues` only sets the value (as the name suggests) but no new item is added.

Use `listBox.Items.add` before setting the value, or add the new item with right value in the first place by add.

```
ArrayList list = getListValue();
listBoc.Items.clear();
for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++){
                System.out.println("qsdq " +list.toString()+" "+ list.size());
                listBox.addItem(list.get(i));
            }
```

Comment: `listBox.addItem(getListValue().get(i));`  coz of this the for loop is going in infinite loop..

Comment: Do you have the listbox populated? And the `geListValue()` gets the values from the listbox?

Comment: `geListValue()` returns the array List. No due to this function only it will have some values.

Comment: If the getListValue is not tied to the listbox, it yhould not run into an infinite loop. Try to store the array in a variable, and clear the listbox. See updated answer.

Comment: Ya after taking `getListValue();` in varible it started working.

but i didnot understand y this happened as both `getListValue() and list is arrayList `.. Can you explain.

Comment: I suspect that the getListValue is somehow based on the listBox's values. So when you add another element into the listbox, it appears in the arraylist of the getListValue. So basically you keep adding elements infinitely to the list. But that is jsut a guess, I may need to know the code of the getListValue.